# ERROR TypeError: "this.exemployees is undefined"

Tags: angular

I'm learning Angular, and during practice I'm getting an error. Please help me  resolve this error, and understand what caused it.

I have created a form where I will add employee details, and on pressing the button a new employee will be added and will be displayed in the table below table.

By clicking the "ex employee" button next to that employee, that employee will be added to the ex-employees array, and will be displayed in the ex-employees array.

On clicking the "ex-employee" button, I'm getting an error.

I have tried debugging, but couldn't understand what causing it.

Below are the console errors:

> ERROR TypeError: "this.exemployees is undefined"
>   ERROR CONTEXT
>   Object { view: {…}, nodeIndex: 108, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…} }

The code:

`parentcomponent.ts`:

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'template-driven';
  employees;
  exemployees;

  constructor(emp_service:EmployeeServiceService) {
      this.employees = emp_service.getEmployeee();
  }

  add_ex_employeee(val) {
      this.exemployees.push(val);
  }

  add_employee(empO) {
      this.employees.push(empO.value);
  }
}
```

`parent component html`:

```
<app-employees [exemployees]="exemployees" (exempadded)="add_ex_employeee($event)" [employees]="employees"></app-employees>
```

`childcomponent.ts`:

```
export class EmployeesComponent implements OnInit {

   @Input('employees') employees;
   @Output('exempadded') exempadded = new EventEmitter();
   @Input('exemployees') exemployees;

   Exclient(ind) {
       this.exempadded.emit(this.employees[ind]);
   }

   ngOnInit() {
   }
}
```

Comment: below is the another error:
ERROR TypeError: "this.exemployees is undefined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried without this two lines?

```
employees;
exemployees;
```

In JavaScript we need not to declare class variables.
We can directly use -

```
this.employees=emp_service.getEmployeee();
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined the `exemployees` array like you have the `employees` array.

In the top of your component:

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'template-driven';
  employees;
  exemployees = [];
```

This way you have made it an array and it has gained the `.push()` function as it's native to the browser.

Comment: thanks it resolved it but i also haven't declared employee array like employee=[ ] but it works and exemployee doesn't please help me to understand

Comment: You've bound `employees` to `emp_service.getEmployeee();` which I assume will return an array of employees or an Observable of employees.

Comment: If you want to use the true power of TypeScript, you would add types to your code so the readability improves and the compiler can help you tell what you're doing wrong or when you're doing something that's not compatible.

Comment: So you've bound `employees` to `emp_service.getEmployees()` which turns it into an array that has the `.push()` method. That's the difference. Your `exemployees` was unbound and didn't contain anything. When you try to use `.push()` on an empty variable; you get a `TypeError` cause `.push()` does not exist on `undefined`.

Comment: Please do upvote and mark as correct answer as well, to help the next person running into something similar.